# Issue installing Composer package, file couldn't be dowloaded

Tags: magento2, composer

I have `"meetanshi/magento-2-defer-parsing-javascript": "1.0.4"` dependencie in my project.
When running `composer install` inside my Dockerfile, I got the following error:

```
- Installing meetanshi/magento-2-defer-parsing-javascript (1.0.4): Downloading (connecting...) Downloading (failed)                                                                                                                                                                                                  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                                                                                             
The "https://repo.magento.com/archives/meetanshi/magento-2-defer-parsing-javascript/meetanshi-magento-2-defer-parsing-javascript-1.0.4.0.zip" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
```

Docker step with `composer install`

```
RUN set -eux; \
    mkdir /var/www/.composer; \
    chown www-data:www-data /var/www/.composer; \
    su -c "cd /var/www/html/ && composer global require hirak/prestissimo" -s /bin/sh www-data; \
    su -c "cd /var/www/html/ && composer install --no-dev --prefer-dist --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader" -s /bin/sh www-data; \
    rm -rf /var/www/.composer;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you might not have the right setup, try to reinstall it using these commands below.

```
composer remove meetanshi/magento-2-defer-parsing-javascript
composer require meetanshi/magento-2-defer-parsing-javascript
```

Then you can run the Magento commands to recognize and compile your Magento.